# How can you use a button to send a vibrational pattern to another iOS device in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, vibration

The user enters another user's phone number. If both people are inside the app simultaneously, each user can tap a big button which makes the other person's device vibrate simultaneously. How can I make the button make the *other* person's iOS device vibrate?

Comment: You can use `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` for haptic feedback and you can configure the selector of the button to make an API call which is received by the other user as a notification or something. This notification would then call the feedback generator.

Comment: Have a look at pusher channels. With pusher you can implement realtime features in your app like you want: https://pusher.com/docs/ios_quick_start

Answer (score 1):

You need to establish some line of communication between the two devices. This is a very vague question, in general, but to get immediate vibration, you'll want some server communicating over a socket with both devices. If one device presses the button, it tells the server to vibrate the other device. The server then tells the other device to vibrate.